# Unsure about unused subview assignment inside a method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I found this code example, inside `- (void)viewDidLoad` method in a regular view controller:

```
UILabel *label  = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"Left Panel";
[label sizeToFit];
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[self.view addSubview:label];
self.label = label;
```

If I comment out the last line, `self.label = label;`, the label still shows up correctly. The `self.label` property is not used anywhere in the method either.

What I'm asking is, what is the purpose for the assignment in that last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without that assignment your controller has a property that doesn't reference the label. The property may not be used elsewhere in that method (it shouldn't be, all of the configuration is done on the local reference), but it should be used somewhere else in the class. Perhaps to update the text / show / hide / something.

The label still shows because you have added it as a subview. The superview retains all of its subviews so the label won't be destroyed.